# Add value to DataFrame to achieve given Standard Deviation

Tags: python, pandas, standard-deviation

Let's say I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this

```
      value
 0      2
 1      6
 2      5
 3      3
 4      7
```

To get the standard deviation I would use [`std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html)

```
>>> df.std()
2.073644
```

How can I determine what value to add to the `DataFrame` so that the standard deviation is equal to a known value e.g. 3?

```
>>> df.loc[5] = ?
>>> df.std()
3
```

Comment: This is a math/statistics question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

sd=old standard deviation

sd'=new standard deviation

M=old mean

n=number of element when old standard deviation was calculated.

x'=new element to be added

x'=(((n+1)*sqroot((n+1)*sd'-nsd))+nM)/n

```
df.loc[5]=x'
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm implementing it incorrectly, but the formula doesn't seem to work. `new_element = ((float(old_n) + 1) * (((old_n + 1) * new_std) - (old_n * old_std))**.5 + (old_n * old_mean))/old_n` I worked it out by hand as well to verify it, the ouput for mean: 4.6, N: 5, old_std: 2.07 and new_std: 3 suggests a new element of 7.9, but the new_std is only 2.29 after I add that.